# Equivalent class for Formatter Class (BB 7) in Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, formatter

I want to know is there any Equivalent class in blackberry 10 for the [Formatter](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/javax/microedition/global/Formatter.html) class

Answer (score 1):

For locale related format, you can use [QLocale](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qlocale.html) : it handles currency, date, numbers...